# Prevent print preview dialog and directly print element

Tags: javascript

How can I print a `div` element with click on print button without opening print preview popup with JavaScript.

```
function printContent(el) {
 var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
 var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
 document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
 window.print();
 document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
}
```

Comment: Print preview popup is browser-dependent, and cannot be controlled programmatically (thank God). If this is a request to help speed up a repetitive workflow, your power users will eventually learn to just hit the Enter key when the popup appears, as they will have already configured the correct printer settings.

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer:

**No**.

However, you could develop browser extension that might be capable of doing so. Thought, it would be way too much effort for little result.

Comment: you mean like [this](https://support.dealpos.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001463387-Printing-Without-a-Print-Preview-in-Chrome-Browser)

Comment: @lipon that's not a browser extension, that's a command line flag for starting the browser. However I have little reason to believe that this is possible from a browser extension either unless a source is provided.

Comment: could you suggest an extension

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I am not sure it is possible either, I am just saying that (thanks god) it ain’t possible via normal JavaScript means... also I would bet that cross browser compatibility would be nightmare.